Compare $ \frac{5y-2x}{2x-2y} $ and $ \frac{5}{2x} + \frac{2}{2y} $
Given that $x,y$ are real numbers and $xy > 0$, and given that:
Quantity A:
$$ \frac{5}{2x} + \frac{2}{2y} $$
Quantity B:
$$ \frac{5y-2x}{2x-2y} $$
If the information provided is enough : Which one is greater?
If there is not enough information to conclude : Give a specific counter-example.

My Attempt:
If $y=2x$ then
Notice that Quantity B can be simplified as $\frac{8x}{-2x}=-4$.
Quantity A can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{3x}$.
By this I can have a counter-example to conclude that any of them cannot be absolutely greater than the other one. If $x>0$, then $A > B$, but if $x = -0.0000001$ then $A < B$.

But what I would like to ask is whether there is a quicker, simple, or logical way than my method above, since this question is meant for broader audience.
Alternatively, is there an algebraic method or strategy to solve this type of problem in general?

I am going to compare the quantities $\;\dfrac{5y-2x}{2x-2y}\;$ and $\;\dfrac5{2x}+\dfrac2{2y}\;$ in the case that $\;x>0\;$ and $\;y>0\;.$
$\boxed{\;\\[3pt]\mathbf{\;Property\;1}:\\\text{ If }\,y\!\leqslant\!\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)\!\text{ or }\,y\!>\!x\,,\,\text{then }\,\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}\!<\!\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\,\\[3pt]}$
Proof:
If $\;y\leqslant\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)\;,\;$ then $\;5y-2x\leqslant\dfrac{6x}{x+4}\;$ and
$2x-2y\geqslant\dfrac{6x}5\left(\!1\!-\!\dfrac2{x\!+\!4}\!\right)\!>0\;,\;$ consequently,
$\begin{align}\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}&\leqslant\dfrac{\frac{6x}{x+4}}{\frac{6x}5\left(\!1\!-\!\frac2{x+4}\!\right)}=\dfrac{5\cdot2x}{2x(x\!+\!2)}=\dfrac5{2x}\left(2\!-\!\dfrac4{x\!+\!2}\right)\!<\\[3pt]&<\dfrac5{2x}\left(2\!-\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!7}\right)=\dfrac5{2x}\left(1\!+\!\dfrac{x\!+\!4}{x\!+\!7}\right)=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac5{2x}+\dfrac5{2x}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x\!+\!4}{x\!+\!7}\leqslant\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac1y=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;.\end{align}$
On the other hand,
if $\;y>x\;,\;$ then $\;5y\!-\!2x>3x>0\;$ and $\;2x\!-\!2y<0\;,\;$ hence
$\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}<0<\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;.$
$\boxed{\;\\[3pt]\mathbf{\;Property\;2}:\\\text{ If }\;\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)\leqslant y<x\;,\;\text{ then }\;\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}>\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;\;\\}$
Proof:
Since $\;\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)\leqslant y<x\;,\,$ it follows that
$5y\!-\!2x\geqslant\dfrac{6x}{x\!+\!2}\;$ and $\;0<2x\!-\!2y\leqslant\dfrac{6x}5\left(\!1-\!\dfrac2{x\!+\!2}\!\right)$, hence
$\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}\geqslant\dfrac{\frac{6x}{x+2}}{\frac{6x}5\left(1\!-\!\frac2{x+2}\right)}=\dfrac5x=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac5{2x}>\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac1y\;.$
$\boxed{\;\\[3pt]\mathbf{\;Remark}:\\\text{ If }\;\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)<y<\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)\;,\;\text{ then}\qquad\qquad\\\text{there exist }(x,y)\text{ such that }\;\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}<\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;\;\text{ ,}\qquad\\ \text{there exist }(x,y)\text{ such that }\;\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;\;\text{ and}\qquad\\\text{there exist }(x,y)\text{ such that }\;\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}>\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\qquad\qquad\\}$
Proof:
There exists $\;(x,y)=\left(2,\frac54\right)\;$ which satisfies the condition
$\dfrac65=\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)<y<\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)=\dfrac75\;$ such that
$\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}=\dfrac32<2<\dfrac{41}{20}=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;.$
There exists $\;(x,y)=\left(2,\frac43\right)\;$ which satisfies the condition
$\dfrac65=\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)<y<\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)=\dfrac75\;$ such that
$\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}=2=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;.$
And there exists $\;(x,y)=\left(2,\frac{27}{20}\right)\;$ which satisfies the condition
$\dfrac65=\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!4}\!\right)<y<\dfrac25x\!\left(\!1\!+\!\dfrac3{x\!+\!2}\!\right)=\dfrac75\;$ such that
$\dfrac{5y\!-\!2x}{2x\!-\!2y}=\dfrac{55}{26}>2>\dfrac{215}{108}=\dfrac5{2x}\!+\!\dfrac2{2y}\;.$

Let's rewrite $A$ and $B$ as:
$$A=\dfrac5{2x}+\dfrac1y=\dfrac{5y+2x}{2xy}$$$$B=\dfrac{3y+(2y-2x)}{2x-2y}=\left(\dfrac32\times\dfrac{y}{x-y}\right)-1$$
For $0<x<y$, we have $B<0<A$.
However, for $x=2.000001$ and $y=2$ we have $B>A$.

Section 1 : Here is a quicker heuristic trick to use
Explaining will take more time & lots of text , even though this is a quick intuitive way !
When $xy$ is Positive , then (Case 1) both $x$ & $y$ have to be Positive or (Case 2) both have to be Negative.
Checking $A$ , we see that it can be either (Case 1) only Positive or (Case 2) only Negative.
Checking $B$ , we see that in either Case 1 or Case 2 , it can be either Positive (when $x$ & $y$ are in some moderate Intervals) or Negative & unbounded to $-\infty$ (when $x$ is very much larger than $y$ or $x$ is very much smaller than $y$)
That is enough to conclude that either $A<B$ or $A>B$ can occur , there is not enough information.

This Diagram is a visualization for the heuristics , not meant to be accurate.
Here the Purple Curve "might" be $B$ , while $A$ "might" be the Blue Solid Curves in Case 1 & the Blue Dashed Curves (mirrored !) in Case 2.
When top-most Curve-1 occurs , then the bottom-most Curve-4 will occur too , just by changing Signs : either $A<B$ or $A>B$ can occur.
When Curve-2 occurs , then the Curve-3 will occur too , just by changing Signs : either $A<B$ or $A>B$ can occur.
This suggests that we want some moderate $x$ value (with suitable moderate $y$ value) where $B$ is Positive & $A$ is greater. We can just change the Signs for $x$ & $y$ to make $A$ Negative & thus lesser.
Hence we try with $(x,y)=(2,1)$ , where $(A,B)=(2.25,0.50)$ : $B<A$
Change the Signs to get $(x,y)=(-2,-1)$ , where $(A,B)=(-2.25,0.50)$ : $B>A$
Your way is good , though you should try with the more general $y=ax$ & then later (at the end) you can choose a suitable $a$ value.
Let $y=ax$ , then $xy=ax^2$ , hence $a$ is Positive , though otherwise arbitrary.
Section 2 : OP wanted algebraic method or strategy
We can make the Equation $A=B$ in terms of $x$ & $y$.
Simplifying & solving the Quadratic Equation , we will get $x$ via some easy-to-calculate terms.
Here , we can plug-in some valid $y_0$ value to generate the valid $x_0$ value.
We can then take some suitable $y_1=y_0+\Delta y$ & $y+2=y_0-\Delta y$ to get $x_1=x_0+\Delta x$ & $x_2=x_0-\Delta x$
These 2 Points $(x_1,y_1)$ & $(x_2,y_2)$ should ideally lie on either side , that is $A<B$ & $A>B$

Clearly $x,y$ must be non-zero and have a same sign. Now let's substitute $a=\frac{5}{2x}$, $b=\frac{1}{y}$, then we still require $a,b$ to have a same sign and we are comparing $a + b$ and $\frac{5b-5a}{-5b+2a}$. The problem is equivalent, but we have fewer fractions...
Now if $a,b$ are both positive $a+b$ is positive, let's see if the second quantity can be made negative. Clearly it suffices to have $5a>2a>5b$ (making numerator negative and denominator positive). So any positive $a,b$ with $2a>5b$ will do, for example $a=3,b=1$, translating to $x=\frac{5}{6},y=1$.
For $a,b$ both negative, we see that $a+b$ is negative. If we make the other quantity positive, we get an inequality in the other direction. It's clear that $5a<5b<2a$ suffices as it makes both numerator and denominator positive. So for example $a=-2,b=-1$, translating to $x=-\frac{5}{4}$,$y=-1$.
